# How to hide toolbar when scrolling on Fragment

Tags: android, hide, toolbar

I have a main activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameInicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="example" />


        <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In FrameLayout "frameInicio" I load a fragment with this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeApuestas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerApuestas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want when scroll in RecyclerView in Fragment, Toolbar of main_activity_layout, hides. How can I do?

I tried with recycler in the same activity, but i don't wanna do this, I want with diferent fragment, because I have a bottom navigation to control diferent fragment.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Im facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced your problem but the only difference is I'm scrolling within listview. Anyway I think that solution can be applied on your recyclerview too.

1. first this is how your fragment.xml should look like

   ```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll|snap">
     </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
       android:id="@+id/swipeApuestas"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerApuestas"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
2. don't forget to initialize the toolbar within the fragment

Comment: also you have to make your style.xml file look like this
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

        />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For your Main Activity (not fragment)